# Multiple Identities in ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I am migrating an ASP.NET Core 1.0 application to ASP.NET Core 2.0.

In my startup I am configuring two identities:

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(configureIdentity)
   .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
   .AddUserStore<IdentityUserStore<IdentityUser>>()
   .AddRoleStore<IdentityRoleStore<IdentityRole>>();

services.AddIdentity<Customer, CustomerRole>(configureIdentity)
   .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
   .AddErrorDescriber<CustomerIdentityErrorDescriber>()
   .AddUserStore<CustomerStore<Customer>>()
   .AddRoleStore<CustomerRoleStore<CustomerRole>>();
```

This worked fine in ASP.NET Core 1.0 but fails with the error: *System.InvalidOperationException: 'Scheme already exists: Identity.Application'* in ASP.NET Core 2.0.

In ASP.NET Core 2.0, if I remove one of the calls to `AddIdentity` the error goes away. How do I migrate my code so that I can use two different types of identity user and role in my application? Or did I just make a fundamental error in understanding how things work back when I wrote this in ASP.NET Core 1.0?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

After looking through the ASP.NET Core source code on github, a second identity could be added using this extension method:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Extensions;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Whatever
{
    public static class IdentityExtensions
    {
        public static IdentityBuilder AddSecondIdentity<TUser, TRole>(
            this IServiceCollection services)
            where TUser : class
            where TRole : class
        {
            services.TryAddScoped<IUserValidator<TUser>, UserValidator<TUser>>();
            services.TryAddScoped<IPasswordValidator<TUser>, PasswordValidator<TUser>>();
            services.TryAddScoped<IPasswordHasher<TUser>, PasswordHasher<TUser>>();
            services.TryAddScoped<IRoleValidator<TRole>, RoleValidator<TRole>>();
            services.TryAddScoped<ISecurityStampValidator, SecurityStampValidator<TUser>>();
            services.TryAddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser>, UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser, TRole>>();
            services.TryAddScoped<UserManager<TUser>, AspNetUserManager<TUser>>();
            services.TryAddScoped<SignInManager<TUser>, SignInManager<TUser>>();
            services.TryAddScoped<RoleManager<TRole>, AspNetRoleManager<TRole>>();

            return new IdentityBuilder(typeof(TUser), typeof(TRole), services);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It really helped much. But why do we had to add Create a builder method; `AddSecondIdentity`?

Comment: @ShiroiTora, I'm not sure I fully understand the question: do you mean *is it necessary to use an extension method?* or do you mean *why did Microsoft change the design in this way?*

Comment: I will go with first question. In startup, I used `services.AddIdentity<..>` for my first Identity then used `services.AddSecondIdentity<..>` for my second Identity. Why do we needed this extension method?

Comment: @ShiroiTora, it doesn't need to be an extension method, but Microsoft changed the design of the identity provider in .NET Core 2.0 so that `AddIdentity` could not be used to add further identities. I think their design choice means that a single identity should be used and you should handle multiple sources of identities in a single provider. The extension method I've written simply replicates the way .NET Core 1.0 behaved i.e. it is lifted from the source code for .NET Core.

Comment: I understood completely now. Thanks.

Comment: @keith may i ask how to use it?

Comment: @JoebetMutia, it was designed to port code from .NET core 1. If you are already using a second identity in .NET core 1, then this is a drop in replacement, except in my original example the second call is `AddSecondIdentity` rather than `AddIdentity`.

Comment: @ZyxSun nope.. i decided to create a web api call from a project that uses that identity db.

keith thanks for the reply.

Comment: You should also add this line:
 services.TryAddScoped<IUserConfirmation<TUser>, DefaultUserConfirmation<TUser>>();

Answer (score 14):

Asp.net Core 2.2 provides a built-in method for that purpose.

```
AddIdentityCore<TUser>
```

How to use it:

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(configureIdentity)
   .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
   .AddUserStore<IdentityUserStore<IdentityUser>>()
   .AddRoleStore<IdentityRoleStore<IdentityRole>>();

services.AddIdentityCore<Customer>(configureIdentity)
   .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
   .AddErrorDescriber<CustomerIdentityErrorDescriber>()
   .AddUserStore<CustomerStore<Customer>>()
   .AddRoleStore<CustomerRoleStore<CustomerRole>>();

services.AddScoped<RoleManager<Customer>>();
```

In fact, read the implementation of this method from [asp.net core 2.2 github repo](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs)

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Adds and configures the identity system for the specified User type. Role services are not added by default 
    /// but can be added with <see cref="IdentityBuilder.AddRoles{TRole}"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TUser">The type representing a User in the system.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="services">The services available in the application.</param>
    /// <param name="setupAction">An action to configure the <see cref="IdentityOptions"/>.</param>
    /// <returns>An <see cref="IdentityBuilder"/> for creating and configuring the identity system.</returns>
    public static IdentityBuilder AddIdentityCore<TUser>(this IServiceCollection services, Action<IdentityOptions> setupAction)
        where TUser : class
    {
        // Services identity depends on
        services.AddOptions().AddLogging();

        // Services used by identity
        services.TryAddScoped<IUserValidator<TUser>, UserValidator<TUser>>();
        services.TryAddScoped<IPasswordValidator<TUser>, PasswordValidator<TUser>>();
        services.TryAddScoped<IPasswordHasher<TUser>, PasswordHasher<TUser>>();
        services.TryAddScoped<ILookupNormalizer, UpperInvariantLookupNormalizer>();
        services.TryAddScoped<IUserConfirmation<TUser>, DefaultUserConfirmation<TUser>>();
        // No interface for the error describer so we can add errors without rev'ing the interface
        services.TryAddScoped<IdentityErrorDescriber>();
        services.TryAddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser>, UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser>>();
        services.TryAddScoped<UserManager<TUser>>();

        if (setupAction != null)
        {
            services.Configure(setupAction);
        }

        return new IdentityBuilder(typeof(TUser), services);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much for your answer keith. This saved me a lot of time!
One small improvement: I had to configure some options (IdentityOptions) in my case. Like for example: Password Complexity Rules.

I therefore included the registering of the Action setupAction. (This is the same way Microsoft does it within the AddIdentity inside IdentityServiceCollectionExtension)

```
public static class IdentityExtensions
{
    public static IdentityBuilder AddSecondIdentity<TUser, TRole>(
        this IServiceCollection services, Action<IdentityOptions> setupAction)
        where TUser : class
        where TRole : class
    {
        services.TryAddScoped<IUserValidator<TUser>, UserValidator<TUser>>();
        services.TryAddScoped<IPasswordValidator<TUser>, PasswordValidator<TUser>>();
        services.TryAddScoped<IPasswordHasher<TUser>, PasswordHasher<TUser>>();
        services.TryAddScoped<IRoleValidator<TRole>, RoleValidator<TRole>>();
        services.TryAddScoped<ISecurityStampValidator, SecurityStampValidator<TUser>>();
        services.TryAddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser>, UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser, TRole>>();
        services.TryAddScoped<UserManager<TUser>, AspNetUserManager<TUser>>();
        services.TryAddScoped<SignInManager<TUser>, SignInManager<TUser>>();
        services.TryAddScoped<RoleManager<TRole>, AspNetRoleManager<TRole>>();

        if (setupAction != null)
            services.Configure(setupAction);

        return new IdentityBuilder(typeof(TUser), typeof(TRole), services);
    }
}
```

Comment: im confused how did you guys used it?

currently i have this


            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddSecondIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationContext>();

but dont know how to initialize those 2 to use