# DataContext.Users returns empty result in Razor pages

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

Hi I have a problem accessing Users table from a Razor page in ASP.NET Core

I Created an `AppDataContext` class that extends `IdentityDbContext<Models.User, Models.UserRole, string>`

I can use it with other controller classes and services without problems. But when I start working on razor pages the `dataContext.Users` always return empty enumerable. Other `DbSet`s still working properly, only the `Users` not work.

This also happens when I try to access data from other services like `UserManager.Users` or `SigniInManager.UserManager.Users`

Here's some part of my files

AppDataContext

```
public class AppDataContext : IdentityDbContext<Models.User, Models.UserRole, string>
{
    // Other DbSet's

    public AppDataContext(DbContextOptions<AppDataContext> options) : base(options) { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        // Other entities building

        MapIdentityTables(builder);
    }

    private void MapIdentityTables(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<Models.User>().ToTable("Users");
        builder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("Users");
        builder.Entity<Models.UserRole>().ToTable("UserRoles");
        builder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("UserRoles");
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<string>>().ToTable("UserClaims");
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>().ToTable("UserUserRoles");
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>().ToTable("UserLogins");
        builder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<string>>().ToTable("UserRoleClaims");
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<string>>().ToTable("UserTokens");
    }
```

LoginPage.cshtml.cs

```
public class LoginModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly Identity.AppUserManager userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<Models.User> signInManager;
    private readonly Data.AppDataContext dataContext;

    public LoginModel(Identity.AppUserManager userManager, SignInManager<Models.User> signInManager, Data.AppDataContext dataContext)
    {
        this.userManager = userManager;
        this.signInManager = signInManager;
        this.dataContext = dataContext;
    }

    public IList<Model.User> Users { get; private set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        Users = userManager.Users.ToList(); // Empty
        Users = signInManager.UserManager.Users.ToList(); // Empty
        Users = dataContext.Users.ToList(); // Empty
    }
}
```

`User` class

```
public class User : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser
{
    public ICollection<UserDevice> Devices { get; set; }
    public IList<UserPassword> Passwords { get; set; }
}
```

Have I done anything wrong or am I missing something?

**UPDATE**

The problem is gone somehow now after I gave up and do something else. But it's not a solution since the original problem still there if I did the same.

What I have done was to revert all my changes and added `AddSecondIdentity` from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47434573/313666). Created  `StaffUser : IdentityUser` and `StaffUserManager<StaffUser, UserRole>` (same `UserRole` as the original `UserManager`) to handle those new `IdentityUser` objects.

Then I just use `StaffUserManager` and `SignInManager<StaffUser>` instead of `AppUserManager` and `SignInManager<User>` in `Login.cshtml.cs`

```
public LoginModel(StaffUserManager userManager, SignInManager<Models.StaffUser> signInManager, Data.AppDataContext context)
{
    var users = context.Users.ToList() // 1 user
}
```

Which now confuses me further. But I don't have time for this now. I think it has something to do with the `Discriminator` part of the database since the returned user is the one with `StaffUser` discriminator value but there are some others without the discriminator that are not returned.

Comment: May I see your User class. Do you want to use User class with IdentityUser ? If so please take a look on my code https://github.com/Awesome-CMS-Core/Awesome-CMS-Core/blob/master/src/AwesomeCMSCore/Modules/AwesomeCMSCore.Modules.Entities/Entities/User.cs

Comment: @NgôHùngPhúc I've added my `User` class in the original post. And yes, it derived from `IdentityUser`

Comment: Did you solve this issue

Comment: I kind of solved my issue as described in the UPDATE section. But the solution is not relevant with the original problem. So I don't think that I have solved the original problem yet.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add services.AddIdentity

```
 services
                    .AddIdentity<User, ApplicationRole>(options =>
                    {
                        options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                        options.Password.RequiredLength = 4;
                        options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                        options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                        options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;

                        //lock out attempt
                        options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;
                        options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
                        options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 3;
                    })
                    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

If this doesn't work please provide me your source code so I can take a look on it. Perhaps your github.